# Efficiently creating a Pandas DataFrame Column that contains the instance number of a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that you have a Pandas column with the following information:

```
>> df
     num
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
```

The column to the left of the num column is the index column.
I want to create an instance column that tells me what instance of num appears. This is the outcome that I want:

```
>> df
     num  instance
0    0    1
1    1    1
2    1    2
3    2    1
4    3    1
5    3    2
```

Here's the code that I wrote to do this:

```
>> my_list = []
>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
>>    my_list.append(df.loc[index,'num'])
>>    # The IF condition is done to prevent my_list from growing too big.
>>    if len(my_list)>1:
>>        if my_list[len(my_list)-1] == my_list[len(my_list)-2]:
>>            del my_list[:len(my_list)-2]
>>    my_list['instance'] = len([element for element in my_list if \
                                 element == df.loc[index,'num'])
```

This code works perfectly for small DataFrames, but it takes an exorbitantly long amount of time to complete when the num column consists of several million lines. Is there a way of creating the instance column in the manner that I'm thinking without using .iterrows()?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "an instance"? It's not obvious to me, even from looking at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [11]: df['instance'] = df.groupby('num').cumcount()+1

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   num  instance
0    0         1
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    2         1
4    3         1
5    3         2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about. I'm going to have to re-review the features in GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` on 'num' column and call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) with param `method=dense'`:

```
In [5]:
df['instance'] = df.groupby('num').transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense'))
df

Out[5]:
   num  instance
0    0         1
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    2         1
4    3         1
5    3         2
```